# Setting variable in Makefile through shell script logic or native make logic but assigning default value when not found in environment variable

Tags: make

I have something like the snippet below. How do I properly set an undefined ENV var in the Makefile through shell script logic? Everything seems to work when the ENV var is already defined in the environment when the script runs, but when not, it's not setting it to the default value (stays empty/unset).

I would have preferred to do something like `FROM_ENV_VAR=${FROM_ENV_VAR:-"default value"}`, but does Makefile syntax have something similar to that to set a variable from some other ENV var (which could be same var of course) otherwise assign a default value to it.

```
MAKE_VAR=fromake

.PHONY: trial

trial:
    if [ -z ${FROM_ENV_VAR} ]; then \
        FROM_ENV_VAR="defaulting"; \
        echo "setting VAR since not defined from ENV, val: ${FROM_ENV_VAR}"; \
        echo "and make's VAR is ${MAKE_VAR}, from shell script"; \
    else \
        echo "using ENV VAR's defined value: ${FROM_ENV_VAR}"; \
        echo "and make's VAR is ${MAKE_VAR}, from shell script"; \
    fi

    echo "in make, make var is $(MAKE_VAR)"
    echo "in make, shell var is $(FROM_ENV_VAR)"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the conditional variable assignment operator `?=`, which will only set the variable if it is not already defined. For more information, see the bottom of [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html) page in the `make` manual.

For example, using the following Makefile:

```
MYVAR?=Set by make

.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo ${MYVAR}
```

You get the following results:

```bsh
$ make
Set by make
$ MYVAR="Set on the command line" make
Set on the command line
```

Comment: Is that standard, or a GNUism?